# How do I delete a single 'block' from a malloc and realloc a new stack with the correct new memory?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, realloc

I have some structs that I am storing data for:

```
typedef struct point
{
    double x, y, z;

} point;

typedef struct vector
{
    double x, y, z;

} vector;

typedef struct triangle
{
    point *corner;
    double normvec[3];
    int chopped;

} triangle;
```

Where I also have:

```
triangle *trilist;
triangle *triptr;
triangle *tmp;
point *pt1ptr;
point *pt2ptr;
point *pt3ptr;
```

I want to write a function that can delete the unit at 'i'.  How would I go about doing this? Here is my awful attempt so far... (HINT: it definitely doesn't work!) and what about freeing this?

```
void deletetriangle(struct triangle *triptr, int totaltri, int i)
{
    tmp = (triangle *) realloc(trilist, (totaltri-1)*sizeof(triangle));
    for (int c = i; c < totaltri - 1; c++)
    {
        trilist[c] = trilist[c+1];
        printf("%d %d/n", i, c);
    }

    for(i=0;i<storage;i++)
    {
        triptr=&(trilist[i]);
        free(triptr->corner);
    }

    trilist = tmp;

}
```

Thank you for any help! This is how I've freed the original memory at the end of the program:

```
    for(i=0;i<storage;i++)
    {
    triptr=&(trilist[i]);
    free(triptr->corner);
    }

    free(trilist);
```

Comment: Shift the remaining items first, realloc afterwards.  Your second `for` loop needs to access `trilist[totaltri-1]`, which after the `realloc` is no longer there.

Comment: @Nate: *None* of `trilist` is available after the realloc, unless the realloc failed. (OK, in practice realloc probably does nothing. But it could.)

Comment: @alexandra: I don't know what your data structures are intended to contain, but it seems odd to me that after you delete a single triangle, you proceed to free the corners of all the triangles up to `storage`, a mysterious variable whose value may be wrong after trilist is reallocated and whose purpose is not at all obvious from the name you chose for it.